# sharing emacs killed text with gnu screen

Tags: linux, emacs, gnu-screen, clipboard

I'd like to automatically have text I kill in emacs get put into screen's clipboard. I don't care too much about travel the other direction. I can do it now via a temporary file, but I have to run a command to grab the data in screen each time.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the variable `interprogram-cut-function` to have a value that is a function you write that pushes all killed text into screen's clipboard (and probably also your window system's clipboard via `x-select-text`, which is the default value).  So you would end up adding code similar to the following to your `~/.emacs` file:

```
(setq interprogram-cut-function 'my-interprogram-cut-function)

(defun my-interprogram-cut-function (text)
  "... docstring here ..."

  ;; First, do the default action.
  (x-select-text text)

  ;; Next, push the killed text into screen (somehow).
  ...)
```

The part at the end will probably involve running a process with `start-process`.